# MVC data read from database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing my MVC application. I have connected it to my database via entity framework. In my controller I run the view like this:

```
public ActionResult MyMarks()
{
    ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1 entities=new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
    return View(entities.Users.ToList());
}
```

My view is:

```
@using ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Marks";
}
<div>
    <h4>Account information</h4>
    <hr/>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Name</dt>
        <dd>Student's name</dd>
        <dd></dd>
        <dt>Surname</dt>
        <dd>Student's surname</dd>
        <dt>Email</dt>
        <dd>
            @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

How do I replace Student's name and Surname with actual data from entities passed in constructor?

Comment: You shold to build Student model from database, then pass this model to view, and render needed fields inside view.

Comment: You should read about the basics of ASP.NET MVC. For example how to pass model to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add model in view `List<Users>`

```
@using ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model List<Users>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Marks";
}
<div>
    <h4>Account information</h4>
    <hr/>
    @foreach(var student in Model) 
    {
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Name</dt>
            <dd>@student.Name</dd>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Surname</dt>
            <dd>@student.surname</dd>
            <dt>@student.Email</dt>
            <dd>
                @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
            </dd>
        </dl>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the top of your view

```
@model List<Users> // you must resolve the namespace like YourProject.Users
```

This specifies what kind of model your view is expecting. Since you are passing `entities.Users.ToList()` we set the View to accept the same.

Now to display the records we can just do a `foreach` loop and access the data in each iteration.. Like

```
@foreach(var user in Model)
{
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>@user.name</dd>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your controller request is list of `Users object` it needs `IEnumerable<ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models.Users>` model that accepts it.

```
 @model IEnumerable<ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models.Users>
 @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "My Marks";
 }
 <div>
 <h4>Account information</h4>
 <hr/>

 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Sure name</th>
 <th>Email</th>
 </tr>

 foreach(var student in Model) 
 {
 <tr>
 <td>@student.Name</td>
 <td>@student.SurName</td>
 <td>@student.Email</td>
 </tr>
 }
 </table>
```